# Not able to browsing the facebook albums in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making one application in which I want to browse all the albums of facebook. I used the following tutorial for it.

http://huguesjohnson.com/programming/java/android-fb-album/

But not able to get the single data. I am getting null response from the facebook server.

Can anyone help me to get facebook albums and its photos?

Here is my code.

```
public class getUserImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            try
            {
             //invoke the API to get albums
              long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
              RestClient client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/" + PreferenceData.getUserId(FacebookIntegrationActivity.this) + "/albums?access_token="+mFacebook.getAccessToken());
              String albumsJson=client.execute(0);
              long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
              Log.d("==","Time to download albums="+(endTime-startTime)+"ms");
              Log.d("==","Album Json="+albumsJson);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you've linked to doesn't include any authentication or login code as far as I can tell - I don't know to what extent you've implemented this. From your code, with the access token added 'manually' it doesn't look like you are using the [Facebook Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) to authenticate the user and log her in.

[These examples](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples)  include code that use the SDK to do auth/login on Android.

You need to ask for the "user_photos" permission from the user to be able to request album data successfully.

After you've authenticated and logged in the user, you can retrieve the albums by calling

```
mFacebookAsyncRunner.request(USER_ID+"/albums",new AlbumRequestListener());
```

where AlbumRequestListener extends the SDK's RequestListener.